# Generate all possible outcomes from pattern or range

Tags: vb.net, text-processing

I have multiple patterns that I want to expand. Expansion should expand number and letter ranges between curly braces. Numbers need to support padding. I want to have it expand into a `List(Of String)` for ease of iteration. Patterns may include multiple sets of curly braces and they can be in any position.

Here are some example patterns and what they should expand to:

Example 1

```
randomtext-aaa-bbb-ccc-{08-10}_abc
    randomtext-aaa-bbb-ccc-08_abc
    randomtext-aaa-bbb-ccc-09_abc
    randomtext-aaa-bbb-ccc-10_abc
```

Example 2

```
other_random*text={1-2}
    other_random*text=1
    other_random*text=2
```

Example 3

```
{01-02}_more_random-things
    01_more_random-things
    02_more_random-things
```

Example 4

```
yet-another#random_example-{a-d}
    yet-another#random_example-a
    yet-another#random_example-b
    yet-another#random_example-c
    yet-another#random_example-d
```

I tried using for loops and sub strings, but it very quickly got confusing and illegible. So how would I go about this without having confusing, illegible code?

Comment: Which part are you having problems with? Parsing the pattern or generating the the strings?

Comment: Maybe this question is better suited for [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi). Add the code that works best so far, show the current actual outcome, and ask for modifications of your code. (And if you do that, delete the question here to avoid crossposts).

Comment: @Rufflewind Parsing the pattern

Comment: @JanDoggen I would, but I asked one question that got too many down votes and now my account is banned from asking questions.

Comment: @Timberwolf http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th?lq=1

Comment: It was closed as to localized. Not much I could do. I wasn't trying to get banned. I'm trying to correct it by answering questions, but... only one has been marked as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> So how would I go about this without having confusing, illegible code?

You can either solve the generating problem with recursion or with dynamic data structures that mimic the effect of recursion.

Both are confusing if you don't now the concept yet, but recursion will stop being illegible once you understand it, while the custom data structures will likely remain illegible for good. The obvious recommendation is for you to learn recursion - it is one of the few programming concepts that will almost certainly make you a better programmer, and that will stay with you throughout your career, log after you've solved this one problem.

Comment: Would mind providing a good source with visual references? I'm more of a visual learner.